# Eclipse JBoss Plugin has wrong PATH to JBoss Home Dir

Tags: eclipse, url, plugins, jboss, path

Basically, I installed the JBoss plugin, then moved my JBoss install directory and changed my Windows environment variable to the new, correct path. However, Eclipse seems to still have the old path so every time I try to run the server it can't find it. How can I change this URL? Should I just reinstall? I'm sure there's a simple answer!

Thanks for your time.

Cheers,
Lindsay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust eclipse variables by going to **window**->**preferences** and then type in the filter "classpath" or "variables" or both. Then go to the **classpath variables** and you should be able to see and change the eclipse JBOSS_HOME.

**EDIT** : If your JBoss runtime does not use the workspace settings, you can change the properties of your server runtime by selecting it in the **servers view** and **Alt-Enter** for a properties view where you can adjust the server location by clicking the **Switch Location** button. You can also double-click on the server for the big properties view in the editor.

Comment: I couldn't see JBoss home in the Classpath, but many of my other variables (also the old values) I found in the "Classpath Variables". I added JBoss to the Classpath Variables in eclipse, but When I started the JBoss Runtime Server, it atill showed it using the old URL.

Comment: I edited the answer, considering that there are multiple ways to set the location of your JBoss runtime

Comment: I was able to fix the issue by going to Window > Preferences >> Server >>> Runtime Environment, and from there editing the JBoss Server to point to the correct location. Thank you for your fast replies!

Comment: there's always another way :)